# How to use Quartz.NET with ASP.NET Core Web Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, quartz.net

In traditional `ASP.NET` application, we (re-)intialize the `Quartz.NET` scheduler in the `Application_Start` handler in `global.asax.cs`.
But I have no ideas where to write the code for scheduling jobs as there isn't `global.asax.cs` in **`ASP.NET` Core Web application**.
Should I put the code in  `Startup.cs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `ConfigureServices` or `Configure` methods.
Although `Configure` method is mainly used to configure the HTTP request pipeline, the benefit is that you directly can use `IHostingEnvironment` (and so get configuration settings) and `ILoggerFactory` interfaces. And using `ConfigureServices` method those dependencies may be accessed if you create corresponding properties in `Startup` class.

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
// For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
```

Answer (score 3):

In the Startup.cs file, this is the equivalent in asp.net core.

You can even create an extenion method for the IServiceCollection  class in order to make the code clean, so the code should look like

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddQuartz(new QuartezOptions {});
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
  app.UseQuartz();
}
```